# I am getting deployment error while calling my apex class in LWC, Unable to activate Apex Language server

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

#### apex class

```
global class UserLoginController {
    @AuraEnabled
    global static String login(String userName, String passWord){
         String homeUrl = ' https://nttdata-32c-dev-ed.my.site.com/s/';
         ApexPages.PageReference PageRef = Site.login(userName, passWord, homeUrl);
        return PageRef.getUrl();
}

}
```

### Js file

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import login from '@salesforce/apex.UserLoginController.login';
export default class LoginPage extends LightningElement {

    email;
    password;
    handleUsername(event){
        this.email = event.target.value;
    }
    handlePassword(event){
        this.password = event.target.value;
    }
    handleButton(){
        console.log("Inside login:");
        console.log("Email value:", this.email);
        console.log("Password:", this.password);
     

        if(this.email !=null && this.password != null){
            login({userName:this.username, passWord:this.password})
            .then((result)=>{
                console.log('result is:', result);
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.log('Error is: ', error);
            })

        }
    }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Amazon Login Page">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                <!-- logo/Branding -->
                <div class="slds-col">
                  <p class="fontsizeCustomn">Sign In</p>
                </div>
                <!-- input type -->
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <lightning-input type="text" variant="standard" label="UserName" name="name" placeholder="Enter User Name" value={email} onchange={handleUsername}></lightning-input>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <lightning-input type="password" variant="standard" label="Password" name="name" placeholder="Enter Password" value={password} onchange={handlePassword}></lightning-input>
                </div>
                <!-- login Button -->
                <div class="slds-col">
                  <div class="button" onclick={handlelogin}> Log In</div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: The error message mostly looks like IDE related rather than a deployment failure. Can you deploy the same code via Developer console or meta apis and check?

Comment: developer console doesn't support LWC and not aware of meta apis

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the error? Is it a deployment issue or an issue in the component itself. The error you have stated is an error with VS code and probably isn't anything to do with your LWC (like @NagendraSingh said). There is probably another error message somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the Apex Language Server. It was not able to load.
I fixed it with the following steps:

1. Go to Settings in VS Code and search for "salesforcedx-vscode-apex".
2. Look for the Java: Home entry and paste the path of your Java jdk folder.
3. If you don't have Java installed, I recommend to download the newest 17 version. Use this path, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17. Version 18 is not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks for information